# IntelliJ IDEA 12 versus sbt 0.13

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am updating a couple of projects to sbt 0.13. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 12 (not interested in EAP 13 at this moment). I am using the sbt plugin by orfjackal. By default it uses an **`sbt-launch.jar`** bundled with IDEA. At least the settings claim that. That has version 0.12 and cannot be launched now because of some JLine incompatibility.

If I go to Settings -> Project Settings -> SBT -> IDE Settings, and specify the 0.13 launcher as custom jar, it works while IntelliJ is open. But the settings are lost when I quit and restart IntelliJ.

So my new idea is to try to replace the bundled sbt-launch.jar. If I open the app bundle (OS X) and search for that name, nothing shows up.

**Where is the bundled sbt-launch.jar and how can I swap it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that SBT jar is located inside your configuration directory. Usually it is something like `~/.IntelliJIdea12`, so simple search in this directory gave `~/.IntelliJIdea12/system/sbt/sbt-launch.jar`. Try replacing it.

BTW, [there is currently](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/07/17/sbt-plugin-nightly-builds/) a new official SBT plugin being developed by JetBrains. It really is great and simplified SBT usage inside IDEA a lot (esp. dependency management), but it does not have embedded console yet (it will, soon). You can try it out even in 12.X IDEA.

Comment: Thanks. I found it in `~/Library/Caches/IdeaIC12/sbt/sbt-launch.jar`.